# Save the original image + draggable blur mask applied to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I was wondering if there is any way to save image original + Draggable blur mask over image

Here is an example of a draggable blur mask over the image : https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/AXRabW

```js
$(function() {
  $("#mask").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#mask {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  left: calc(50% - 25px);
}

#unblurred {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}

#unblurred img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#blurred {
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="mask">
  <div id="unblurred">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRVsxe5OJVY/maxresdefault.jpg">
  </div>
</div>

<img id="blurred" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRVsxe5OJVY/maxresdefault.jpg">
```

Wanted to save image with draggable blur mask over image... Maybe using canvas or something of the type

Comment: I was testing with `html2canvas` but the draggable circle does not get rendered...

Comment: After some research it turns out that `html2canvas` does not support `-webkit-filter` yet: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/493

Comment: If using `filter: blur ()` is capable of working?? I need to do some tests

Comment: I switched `-webkit-filterto` to `filter` and changed the order (unblur to blur and vice versa) the generated image is all blurred... It is partially working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I have a some what working solution, here is the JS code:

```js
function saveMask() {
    $("#blurred").hide()
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#mask"), {allowTaint: true}).then(h2c => {
        var pos = $("#mask")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        $("#mask").hide()
        var image = document.getElementById('blurred');
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.width = image.width;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        ctx.filter = 'blur(20px)'
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        ctx.filter = 'none'
        ctx.drawImage(h2c, pos.x, pos.y);

        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    });
}
```

My idea here is to get as the mask using html2canvas and then we create a canvas with the blurred image and "paste" the mask on top of that.

I have a fully functional example here:
https://raw.githack.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/master/HTML/html2canvas.html

Comment: Glad I could help, you probably noticed that I had to change the draggable circle to a square, getting the circle was problematic because it was adding a white background to the transparent area.

Comment: Hello I solved the problem of the circle ... I was taking a look at the documentation of the html2canvas (http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/) and found what we needed ... Here is the updated example .... (https://codepen.io/carlos-henreis/pen/OwZqzL)

All thanks to your help. Thank you very much